# zsh で、 brew でインストールされている zsh 補完を一括で利用可能にしたい

Tags: homebrew, zsh

brew でパッケージをインストールしていくと、 zsh の completion コードが付属している場合があることに気づきました。それらは、パッケージをインストールした際のメッセージによれば、 `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions` に配置される様子です。

```
zsh completions have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

#### 質問

- brew で入ってくる zsh の補完を on にするには、どうしたらいいでしょうか。
- また、上記のディレクトリをのぞいてみたところ、ある種の規則に従った naming convention でファイルたちは作られているように見受けられます。これらを一括で利用できるようにするような、 zsh のプロファイリングスクリプトを作るとしたら、どのようになりますでしょうか。

インストールされている zsh completion 一覧

```
$ ls  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions 
_aws                    _brew_cask              _gibo                   _heroku                 aws_zsh_completer.sh
_brew                   _brew_services          _git                    _kubectl                git-completion.bash
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compinit` (大抵は`.zshrc`に記載すると思いますが）の一行前に、
`autoload -U compinit` の記述はしておられますか？
つまり、
`.zshrc`の中に記載されるべきは、

```
autoload -U compinit
compinit
```

この順番に、2行になります。
もう一つ見落としやすいのは`/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`のパーミッションですね
。
これで`TAB`キーでの補完が可能になると思います。

Comment: todashuta さんの回答と合わせて、補完が動作するようになりました。

Answer (score 2):

fpathに加えると使えるようになります

具体的には、.zshrcの`compinit`よりも前の行に、下記のコードを追加します。

```
fpath=(/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions $fpath)
```

Comment: 一つ、 `compinit` とはコマンドでしょうか。というのも、 `.zshrc` の末尾に、 `compinit` を追加してみたところ、 `command not found: compinit` のエラーメッセージが出力されており、どうやら自分は何か勘違いしているかもしれないと思っています。